# HDD to SSD file transfer very slow

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, performance, sata

I'm using Fedora 22 Linux, and just got a brand new Samsung 850EVO 250GB SSD.
I'm trying to move some of my files (mostly, my most-used games) from my old HDD to my new SSD but the transfer speed is nowhere near what I expected.

hdparm shows the read speed of the HDD at 105mb/s and the read speed of the SSD at 520mb/s but the files are transfering at less than 20mb/s.

Both drives are connected to Sata 3 ports and i've tried replacing both SATA cables with brand new ones, and saw no change.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: they are connected to SATA_1 and SATA_2 on the motherboard both slots are sata 3.0 ports. Both file systems are ext4

Comment: What size are the files? How are you copying them?

Comment: though GUI using caja.  Files vary in size from a few kb to 20gb

Comment: Try to use `rsync` with the option for sparse files. It can happens, for example, if you find directory with a wide number of files (thousands) or if you transfer some big files on a _wrong_ file system.  Can you [edit] your question adding info as if they are connected to the same port and which kind of  File System they have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. The read speed of your HDD from hdparm is the maximum sequential read speed under ideal conditions. **You will not achieve this speed while copying multiple files in the real world.**

A HDD can only reach its maximum sequential transfer rate if it never has to move the head (seek). Each time your hard drive has to move the read/write head, you lose around 2% of your read speed.

If you are copying lots of small files, or a single large file split into many parts, your drive may need to move the head dozens of times per second, which can drag your speed down to less than 0.5MB/sec under worst-case conditions.